# Vue.js and javascript, how should I append the correct string to my URL?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I made a website.

I currently have a form and a link next to the form. When the user clicks on the link, whatever is typed in that form will be added to the url path of `/funpage/`, and become the new URL path. So for example, If the user types something like `/hey/hi` then clicks on the link. The link will take the user to a URL like `/funpage/hey/hi`. Another example, Is if the user types something like `/hellooy/hi/hey/whatsup/hi` then clicks on the link. The link will take the user to a URL like `/funpage/hellooy/hi/hey/whatsup/hi`.

The issue is that my Vue.js application with vue router, will think that the user is going to a new webpage, because the user inputted backslashes that get added to the URL and act like it is a whole new path.

My solution is to write a regex like `/\//g` and use the `replace` function in Javascript, for the user's input into the form, which gets rid of any backslash characters. So when the user types something like `/hey/hi` and clicks on the link, it will just take them to `/funpage/heyhi` which is what I want.

However I am sure that there are more characters that you don't want to be entered into a URL, that I know the user could input and would break it. I know about `encodeURIComponent` but this seems to be only used If you want to purposely add query params.

Does someone possibly have a regex better than `/\//g` to escape all characters that shouldn't be in a URL? or a better solution perhaps.

Thank you!

Comment: There's encodeURI besides encodeURIComponent. Is that what you ask about?

Comment: no, that function doesn't remove the back slashes..

Comment: It doesn't remove back slashes, it's supposed to escape them

Comment: It leaves the backslashes in the string and doesn't escape them, try it in your code editor